# PHP chmod and file_get_content permission problem

Tags: php, file-get-contents, chmod

In PHP, I'm grabbing remote images with:

```
$img = file_get_contents("http://example.com/image.jpg");
file_put_contents("../testdir/photo.jpg",$img);
```

I get a **Permission Denied** error unless testdir is set to chmod 0777.  Which, I tried to do with PHP and then set it back to 0755:

```
chmod("../testdir/", 0777);
$img = file_get_contents("http://example.com/image.jpg");
file_put_contents("../testdir/photo.jpg",$img);
chmod("../testdir/", 0755);
```

but I got **Operation Not Permitted**  Is there a safe, working alternative?

Thanks!

Comment: what? why -1 and close vote? is this a duplicate or something?

Comment: unhappy nerds, expressing their hate for society downvoting stackoverflow questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the *owner* of the directory to be the user which PHP will be running as (typically the same user the web server process - Apache, lighttpd, nginx, whatever - is running as). Then you won't get permission errors.

Comment: Thanks @Amber for the answer. I did just now check the user (with `echo get_current_user()`.  If that's the correct way to check the PHP user, then the directory group owner does match what's returned by that function.

Comment: Nevermind, just found out that `get_current_user()` isn't the way to find out...rather `passthru("whoami");`   Thanks for the help @Amber!